# How to add a border bottom like the image?

Tags: css

I just want to know how can I add a border to the bottom of my container like this:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a551tq923

Assuming the border is white there and the container is above that.

I know it requires some minor CSS but can not figure that out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktusz1s7/) to show an example of what you could do. All using CSS.

I could see multiple ways of accomplishing this using the basic example I provided.

The css used for the bottom slant:

```
#bottom {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 20px solid black;
    border-left: 500px solid transparent;
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is another [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ktusz1s7/3/). More close to the website.

Also the [website](https://frontjet.com/) is using parallax. So it's going to be a little different then what I threw together.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like :

```
#container {
  background:url('path to image which needed as border') no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CSS3 you can do the same of the image that you like, try with:

```
#container {
   border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; 
   -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* firefox */
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* safari, chrome */
}
```

And if you want even the shadow try with:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px #303030;
```